# How to get the 4th order of polynomial from random generated values and reshape array from (100) to (100,4)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to implement the fourth-order of the polynomial and implemented the following logic with the following instructions:

1. first of all, import PolynomialFeatures function from scikit-learn
2. and use it to generate a new X_4d array that has all features up to 4th order features
3. The shape should be (100,4) after transforming to add the higher-order polynomial features, and the first 5
4. samples should look like the following

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

def forth_order(m, a=-3.15, b=1.18, c=3.52, d=3.92, mu=0.0, sigma=0.33):
    new_x = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(m,)).reshape(100,4)
    new_y =  a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d + np.random.randn(m)*sigma
    return(new_x, new_y)

print(new_x)
print(new_x.shape)

print(new_y)    
print(new_y.shape)

# to find the 4th order for random generated values
np.random.seed(42)
# call your function to generate the artificial cubic data set
new_x,new_y = make_cubic_dataset(100)

transformer = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4, include_bias=False)
transformer.fit(new_x).reshape(100,4)
x_ = transformer.transform(new_x)
X_4d = np.polyfit(x, y, 3) # fit a degree 4 (cubic) polynomial to the data

print(X_4d)
print(X_4d.shape)
```

**An error:**

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 100 into shape (100,4)
```

**An expected outcome:**

The shape should be (100,4) after transforming to add the higher-order polynomial features, and the first 5 and samples should look like the following

```
print(X_4d.shape)
>>> (100, 4)

print(X_4d[:5,:])
>>> [[-0.25091976  0.06296073 -0.01579809  0.00396405]
    [ 0.90142861  0.81257354  0.73247704  0.66027576]
    [ 0.46398788  0.21528476  0.09988952  0.04634753]
    [ 0.19731697  0.03893399  0.00768234  0.00151586]
    [-0.68796272  0.4732927  -0.32560773  0.22400598]]
```

I'm facing trouble to solve this issue.

Comment: You can't reshape array with 100 elements (100x1) into matrix with 400 elements (100x4). instead of `np.random.uniform(size=(100,)).reshape(100,4)` just use `np.random.uniform(size=(100, 4))` to create random matrix.

Comment: @Aiven Thank you for your help but I was able to figure it out to transform the result. to generate the output. If you like my answer, please accept the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It was a small change in the code,and it is self-explanatory:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

def forth_order(m, a=-3.15, b=1.18, c=3.52, d=3.92, mu=0.0, sigma=0.33):
    new_x = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(m,)).reshape(-1,1)
    new_y =  a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d + np.random.randn(m)*sigma
    return(new_x, new_y)

np.random.seed(42)

# call your function to generate the artificial cubic data set for forth order
new_x,new_y = forth_order(100)

X_4d = transformer.transform(new_x)
X_4d = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4, include_bias=False).fit_transform(new_x)
transformer.fit(new_x)

print(X_4d.shape)
print(X_4d[:5,:])
```

**Output**

```
print(X_4d.shape)
>>> (100, 4)

print(X_4d[:5,:])
>>> [[-0.25091976  0.06296073 -0.01579809  0.00396405]
    [ 0.90142861  0.81257354  0.73247704  0.66027576]
    [ 0.46398788  0.21528476  0.09988952  0.04634753]
    [ 0.19731697  0.03893399  0.00768234  0.00151586]
    [-0.68796272  0.4732927  -0.32560773  0.22400598]]
```